# php imap is it possible to delete 1 email by email id stackoverflow

Tags: php, email, imap

is it possible to perform imap php function with a given UID ??

because when we do

```
$imapx__ressource = imap_open($imapx__server, $imapx__user, $imapx__password);
$imapx__emails = imap_search($imapx__ressource, $imapx__search);
foreach($imapx__emails as $imapx__email){
     $imapx_headerinfos = imap_headerinfo($imapx__ressource, $imapx__email);
}
```

the $imapx_headerinfos will have UID (email ID)

but what about the inverse ?

I have the UID of a given email, I want to read or delete that specific email.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean the Message-ID header?  Or the IMAP UID?  You can use the UID directly by providing the _UID flags to the various IMAP functions.

Comment: Ih @Max yes the IMAP UID. but how to use it ? in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-delete.php they mention `imap_delete ( resource $imap_stream , int $msg_number [, int $options = 0 ] ) : bool` where options
You can set the FT_UID which tells the function to treat the msg_number argument as a UID. but it's confusing how they explain this...

Comment: In the notes, someone answers this if you want to use the uid, simply option value
`imap_delete($mbox, $uid, FT_UID);` I'll have to test this

Comment: Yes, pretty much every function ahs some variant on the FT_UID flag that says "use the argument as a UID, not a msgno"

Comment: @Max GREAT ;) it works

Answer (score 0):

Here the working solution

When retrieving the emails don't forget to save in DB

```
imap_uid($imapx__ressource, $imapx__email)
```

** NB : the headerinfos->message_id is NOT the same as UID...

```
$imapx__ressource = imap_open($imapx__server, $imapx__user, $imapx__password);
imap_delete($imapx__ressource, $email_UID, FT_UID);
```